# Can derivatives of CC BY-SA works be licensed under CC BY-NC-SA?

Tags: derivative-works, creative-commons, cc-by-sa, cc-by-nc-sa

Does the CC BY-SA license prevent additional restrictions being placed on derivatives?

I'm wondering, if I release a work under BY-SA, can someone else create a derivative and license it under BY-NC-SA?

Comment: SA means "ShareAlike", which means derivative works must use the same license.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it’s not allowed.

It says on the [license summary page](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/):

> **No additional restrictions** — You may not apply legal terms or technological measures that legally restrict others from doing anything the license permits.

And in the [license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode):

- For Licensed Material (i.e., the unmodified work):

  > **No downstream restrictions.** You may not offer or impose any additional or different terms or conditions on, or apply any Effective Technological Measures to, the Licensed Material if doing so restricts exercise of the Licensed Rights by any recipient of the Licensed Material.
- For Adapted Material (i.e., a modified work):

  > You may not offer or impose any additional or different terms or conditions on, or apply any Effective Technological Measures to, Adapted Material that restrict exercise of the rights granted under the Adapter's License You apply.

---

Creative Commons lists [compatible licenses](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/licensing-considerations/compatible-licenses/) for CC BY-SA and CC BY-NC-SA. If it were allowed, it would be listed there.

Comment: The other natural question would be if BY-NC-SA could be licensed under BY-SA. Is it one-way compatible in that sense?

Comment: @Zizouz212: No, they aren’t one-way compatible. The link in the last paragraph of my answer also lists licenses compatible with CC BY-NC-SA (CC BY-SA isn’t one of them). -- If it were allowed, anyone could easily bypass the "NC" restriction, rendering it moot.

Comment: Is using existing work licensed just BY (3.0) allowed to be remixed and published as BY SA (4.0) ? With the same reasoning as your answer, I think not. Correct?